# Is there anything similar to setanalyticscollectionenabled in firebase.firestore()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We use firebase firestore in **Javascript** to store logs of the application.
db = firebase.firestore();

Firestore also stores User's city,state,country. Which I can see in stremView in firebase. Due to Privacy and legal requirement, I would like to stop firestore, collecting user's device and location information.

In analytics they have setanalyticscollectionenabled = false which will stop collecting user's data. What is the option in firebase.firestore similar to this?

How to **block firestore collecting user's device and region info**?

Comment: Firestore doesn't collect any data.  It just stores what you put in it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. may be then city,state I can see in streamView is beacause of googletag manager I was using.2